# Wrong boolean statement

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

My task is to return a boolean expression, if no element from an array contains 2 or 3.

```
boolean no23(int[] nums) 
{
 boolean no23 = false; 

 for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
 {
   if (nums[i]==2 || nums[i]==3)
   {
     no23 = false; 
   }
   else
   {
     no23 = true; 
   }
 }  
 return no23;
}
```

My problem is: If the first number is 3, i got false back, but if the second number is 5, i got true. So the final return is true and that's a mistake.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: to return a boolean expression TRUE, sorry :-)

Comment: regarding this line: `boolean no23(int[] nums)` 1) how is `boolean` defined?  2) the correct format for the parameter is: `int nums[]`   so the code does not compile.    regarding the code logic.  strongly suggest: initialize the return variable to `true` and remove the `else` code block.  in the `if` code block, after setting the return variable to `false`, exit the loop via `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `break;` after `no23 = false;` because once it's false, it's false forever, and you don't need to go any further.

Additionally, if you initialize `no23` to `true`, you don't need to keep setting it in the loop, and can remove the `else` clause entirely.

And once you do that, you may realize you don't need `no23` at all. You can `return false;` if you find a 2 or a 3, and `return true;` at the end of the function, because if it makes it all the way through the loop, it hasn't found a 2 or a 3.

And now you've got this:

```
boolean no23(int[] nums) 
{
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      if (nums[i]==2 || nums[i]==3)
      {
         return false; 
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```